# Recycler View changes item value on scroll

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a Recycler View in my app and rendered data into it. I have two add and subtract button for quantity but the problem is each time while I scroll quantity will change. What to do now. Please help. I have also added getItemViewType,getItemId & getItemCount but still my list changes its value on scroll.

Code:

```
public class AdapterReturnProduct extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterReturnProduct.MyViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    ReturnProductFragment returnFragment;
    ArrayList<ModelReturn> productDataArrayList;
    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    ModelReturn estimationData;
    int qty;


    public AdapterReturnProduct(Context context, ArrayList<ModelReturn> productDataArrayList, ReturnProductFragment returnFragment) {
        this.context = context;
        this.productDataArrayList = productDataArrayList;
        this.returnFragment = returnFragment;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_return, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        estimationData = productDataArrayList.get(position);
        holder.txtProductName.setText(estimationData.getProduct_name());

        holder.txtDelieveredValue.setText(estimationData.getProduct_ordered());


        if (estimationData.getProduct_returned() == (null)) {
            holder.etQty.setText("0");

        } else {
            holder.etQty.setText(String.valueOf(estimationData.getProduct_returned()));
        }


        if (estimationData.getProduct_type().equals("unit")) {
            holder.imgPType.setImageResource(R.drawable.wine_icon_black);
            holder.txtCodeValue.setText(estimationData.getProduct_barcode());
        } else {
            holder.imgPType.setImageResource(R.drawable.black_box);
            holder.txtCodeValue.setText(estimationData.getProduct_barcode());
        }


        holder.ibPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ModelReturn estimationData = productDataArrayList.get(position);

                qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.etQty.getText().toString());
                qty = qty + 1;

                holder.etQty.setText(qty + "");


                returnFragment.upDateReturnedProduct(estimationData.getProduct_id(), estimationData.getProduct_name(),
                        estimationData.getProduct_barcode(), estimationData.getProduct_type(), estimationData.getProduct_ordered(), holder.etQty.getText().toString());

          //                deliveryFragment.updateProductInCart(estimationData.getProductId(), estimationData.getProductName(),
       //                        estimationData.getProductBarcode(), 
                 String.valueOf(qty),estimationData.getProductType());
            }
        });

        holder.ibMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ModelReturn estimationData = productDataArrayList.get(position);


                qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.etQty.getText().toString());
                if (qty > 0) {
                    qty = qty - 1;
                    holder.etQty.setText(qty + "");

                    returnFragment.upDateReturnedProduct(estimationData.getProduct_id(), estimationData.getProduct_name(),
                            estimationData.getProduct_barcode(), estimationData.getProduct_type(), estimationData.getProduct_ordered(), holder.etQty.getText().toString());


                }


            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productDataArrayList.size();
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {


    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView txtProductName, txtCodeValue, txtDelieveredValue;
        ImageButton ibMinus, ibPlus, ibDelete;
        EditText etQty;
        ImageView imgPType;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            txtProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtProductName);
            txtCodeValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCodeValue);
            txtDelieveredValue = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDelieveredValue);
            ibPlus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibPlus);
            ibMinus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ibMinus);

            etQty = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.etQty);
            imgPType = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to notify adapter that dataset has changed
after setting adapter use adapter.notifydatasetchanged()

Comment: @mishti did you solve it or try my solution?

Comment: @Vucko I solved it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your model that's being displayed remains unchanged. After merely replacing the text here:

```
holder.etQty.setText(qty + "");
```

The actual `ModelReturn` that's on that position remains with the old quantity, so the next time you scroll or trigger `onBindViewHolder` again in any other way, it'll display the old value. You should do:

```
ModelReturn estimationData = productDataArrayList.get(position);
// Also consider changing this to use estimationData.getQuantity() rather than reading from the textview
qty = Integer.parseInt(holder.etQty.getText().toString());
if (qty > 0) {
    qty = qty - 1;
    // These two lines RATHER than changing the text manually
    // NOTE: Not sure how your setter is called, edit accordingly
    estimationData.setQuantity(qty);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

    returnFragment.upDateReturnedProduct(estimationData.getProduct_id(), estimationData.getProduct_name(),
                        estimationData.getProduct_barcode(), estimationData.getProduct_type(), estimationData.getProduct_ordered(), holder.etQty.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: It is not showing me old value values leads to change to any number

Comment: I have no idea what you just said. Use punctuation, please. And try to be more descriptive. And yes, it IS showing you the old value cause it relies on the model and not what's inside the textview that you see. The model needs to be in accordance with what's shown at all times.

Comment: It is not fetching old value from the database. When I scroll it, then list item just pick any random number on textview

Comment: Did you even try to put my code in and see if it helps?